# How do I include email attachments to a blog post through incoming email

Tags: 2010, email, blog, incoming-email

I am publishing posts to a SharePoint 2010 blog through incoming email. This is working perfectly but I'd like to send any attachments to an attachments library and include the attachments at the bottom of the post.  Any Ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: So far my best guess is I'll need an Event Receiver since I can't seem to find a way to achieve this through the SP interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the SharePoint help it seems like attachments is out of the box.

"If the Post list is configured to receive attachments, you can include an attachment to your blog post by attaching the file to your e-mail message."

However I'm not sure why there is no option for the attachements. Does anyone know what is missing.

Comment: Thanks, searching for that exact quote I was able to dig up this help article http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/post-to-a-blog-HA010378204.aspx.  So it looks like it's possible, and out of the box, guess I need to dig some more.  Thanks!